# recursion without base case and statements following recursion function

Tags: c++, recursion

When are the statements after the recursion executed if there is no base case ?

```
              void fun(int x,int y){
               statement 1;
               statement 2;
               fun(x',y');
               statement 3;
               statement 4;
               }
```

Here statement 1 and 2 are not the base cases.When will the statements 3 and 4 executed if every recursion sends the control back to the recursive function ?

My question is in reference with this code  https://ideone.com/lEKxW5 .In the link that i have  given, when is the statement after line 24 or say after recursion executed ?

```
             LOOK AT THE LINK OF THE CODE BEFORE ANSWERING .


               void dfsBipartiteColor(int x, int y, int c)
              {
               // If we got to paint the cell:
                  if ( (board[x][y] == 'X') && (color[x][y] == -1) ) {
                   // Color it:
                  color[x][y] = c;
                   // Special case: We have foudn that there is at least one X:
    result = std::max(result, 1);

    // Try the adjacent hexagons:
    for (int nx = max(0, x-1); nx <= min(n-1, x+1); nx++) {
        for (int ny = max(0, y-1); ny <= min(n-1, y+1); ny++) {
            // The hexagon is adjacent and has an X:
            if ( (nx - x != ny - y) && (board[nx][ny] == 'X') ) {
                // continue the DFS, negate the color:
                dfsBipartiteColor(nx,ny, !c);// 
                // Special case: We now know there are two adjacent X:
                result = std::max(result, 2);
                // If the color is not consistent, the graph is not bipartite: 
                if (color[nx][ny] == c) {
                    result = 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When are the statements after recursion executed in the code above ?

Comment: Why not step through the code and find out how it works?  That can be much more enlightening and is a good skill to learn.

Comment: YES  i did it on the code but when are the statements after recursion executed or in which order is not clear to me

Comment: No you did not step through the code.  If you did that it would show you exactly what gets executed and when.

Comment: why dont you post the code here if it is that essential to the question? Btw the code in the link has lots of other errors

Comment: @tobi303 can you exaplain how recursion has been broken in the code ?

Comment: @mathematicalerdos no i cant, because it actually isnt broken ;). I was just to fast in writing the comment, because I dont like to read code in a link that has many other compiler errors. See alains answer, why your snippet is not representative for your actual code.

Answer (score 3):

You have simplified the code too much, there is also a condition:

```
void fun(int x,int y){
    statement 1;
    statement 2;
    if(condition) fun(x',y');
    statement 3;
    statement 4;
}
```

So when the condition is not met, the calls return.

Comment: can you ex[plain by looking at the code in thee link that i have mentioned

Comment: The `for` loops and the `if` create a condition for the recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

The base case seems invisible because it doesn't do anything and occurs when the entry condition is false.
(You left out the entry condition when you simplified.)

Simplifying the code you posted as much as possible:

```
void function()
{
    if (condition)
    {
        function();
        statement;
    }
}
```

If you still can't see the base case, consider the equivalent

```
void function()
{
    if (condition)
    {
        function();
        statement;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They will never be executed, and the program will crash fairly quickly, as soon as it runs out of stack space, due to infinite recursion.

Comment: How can you say this when you do not know what the statements are?  What if one of them is an if statement to break the recursion?

Comment: Questions on stackoverflow.com must include complete content in the question itself, instead of links to external sites that can stop working at any time, rendering the question meaningless. As such, answers are given based solely on the information in the question itself.

Comment: @NathanOliver & tobi303 The question does state that neither statement before the recursion is a base case. To me at least, that implies that they don't return.